# How to Create Dynamic String Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In my Application, I need to save a UITextView's text in NSAttributedString.

When a user **swipes on the screen** then whole text in **UITextView will copy in NSAttributedString** and UITextView will become NIL and then after some writing in UITextView if User will do again Swipe then that Text will also store in another NSAttributedString.

My problem is, I don't know **how many times User will do swipe**.

So, i have to take as many string as many times User will do swipe on screen.

I need to take something Like this

**For Example...**

```
Int var = 5;   
NSAttributedString *strObject(var);
```

So, actually NSAttributedString object is  **strObject5**

"OR" May be Like This...

```
for(Int i=0;i<=var;i++)  
{  
   NSAttributedString *strObject(var);  
}
```

I knew that, this all things are wrong but i need to do something like this.

Any idea, link, code, tutorial will be great Help.....

Comment: Create an NSMutableArray. Each time the user swipes, add the NSAttributedString to the array.

Comment: but in my attribute string there are text written in bold,italic,underline and also bullet points are there. and these all written with NSMutableParagraphStyle. so in adding the NSMutableArray all things will change ?

Comment: Add the NSmutableString to the Array. Everything works fine

Comment: An NSArray or NSMutableArray is a collection of other objects. It does not modify your object unless you instruct it to.

Comment: Yes it works man...Thanks. I'll do as you said for my this app but Is it possible as i above asked ? just asking for future problem...+1 for the solution.